# Docusign - How to disable the "Caution" Dialog after clicking "Decline"?

Tags: docusignapi

When a user clicks "Decline", a "Caution" dialog will pop up, then followed by a decline reason dialog. I want to disable the "Caution" popup, can I do that?

Comment: This dialog is not configurable via the API or your account preferences. It pertains to DocuSign and you might want to share that with them by creating a [feature request in their official forum](https://support.docusign.com/en/forum) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable the "Caution" popup, it is provided to increase the successful transaction rate. This popup gives an option for a signer to reconsider the option before decline, instead click "Finish Later" and contact the sender if he/she has concern related to E-Signature or the documents in the envelope. So giving this popup, we are trying to push for more successful transaction for the customers.